# Is there an App in Appexchange to monitor API call in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, monitoring

How to monitor API calls sent from Marketing cloud and received by marketing Cloud?

Comment: Hi,@Neeliveda. Welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to ready our guide on [How To Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). In your specific question, please tell us what kind of information do you need, what Apps you have found and why then don't help you. The more information you provide, the easier it will be for the community to help you

Comment: @Neeliveda Please mark my answer as accepted, so others can easily see this has been correctly answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no way to do so currently, as no api-endpoint, data view or report is able to provide this information.

I guess the only possible way is asking the assigned account executive, who should be able to tell you if you are close to the limit or not.